# AdMob подключение в xcode swift ошибка : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, admob

Появилась ошибка "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" при подключении admob в свою программу, я весь код писал так, как написано на сайте google developer. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Аналогичная проблема была и у меня. До iOS 9 такого не было, а под девятку, по всей видимости, еще не переписали код. P.S. Сам перепробовал все варианты, но решения не нашел.

Comment: можно всю информацию из ошибки посмотреть?

Comment: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/boris/Desktop/FizMath/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.6-2.0'
ld: '/Users/boris/Desktop/FizMath/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.6.0/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADBannerView.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Это только появляется , когда на реальном устройстве запускаю , а на симуляторе нет такой ошибки

Comment: так все ж написано: у вас включен bitcode, а в admob не включен. надо либо 1) скачать новую версию admob с bitcode, либо 2) отключить bitcode у себя в приложении.

Comment: Так что лучше , и как это сделать , я просто впервые подключаю от admob рекламу

Comment: Все я нашел на интернете , спасибо большое )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdMob пока не поддерижвает bitcode. Так что придется вам либо отказаться от AdMob либо отключить bitcode в своем приложении. [Вот тут](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios9) вся информация.